# Make external API hit from kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes service running and we have an external API's dependent on this service.

We would like to be notified if there is any service restart. Is there any possibility to hit an API endpoint on every service restart?

Comment: checkout init containers

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to the community!

There are multiple ways of achieve this. A really simple one (as pointed out by Thomas) is an Init Container. Refer to the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) for more on how to get those running! This init container would do nothing more than send out an HTTP request to your external API once the pod is started and terminate immediately afterwards.

The other way is much more complex and will require you to write some code yourself. What you'd have to do is write your own controller that watches the entities through the Kubernetes API and notify your external service when a pod is rescheduled, killed, died etc.
(You could however have your external service to exactly that why accessing the kube-api directly...)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [enzian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129334/265026) about using [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). Here is an example using a [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) based initContainer and mounting the metadata to pass as an environment variable in the call:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: some-service
  namespace: the-project
  labels:
    app: some-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: some-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: some-service
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: service-name-init
        image: txn2/curl:v3.0.0
        - name: SOME_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        command: [
          "/bin/sh",
          "-c",
          "/usr/bin/curl -sX GET example.com/notify/$(SOME_NAME)"
        ]
      containers:
      - name: ok
        image: txn2/ok
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
        ports:
        - name: ok-port
          containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick help, it really help. This will help us in calling an api on deployment, But is their any way to call an API on service restart?

Comment: initContainers is called every time the Pod is started, so my example /usr/bin/curl -sX GET example.com/notify/$(SOME_NAME) will get called on start. Pods are not technically re-started, a new one is created and the old one is removed.

Comment: Yes I understand that initContainers will be called on every pod restart. But my requirement is with respect to service public IP. I have dependency on the public IP that service provide and if it changes my other service will start breaking. So I want a way to be notified on this public Ip change.